# prevent DataTables from hiding tooltip

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I've made a custom tooltip with html and css, shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8nnwytbL/593/)

the tooltip itself is all one span element:

```
<span class="data-tooltip tooltip-top error1">Custom tooltip.</span>
```

So I've been inserting the full span elements into my dataTable, which is working. But, unfortunately on mouse-over the tooltip is being blocked by the cell above it like in this image:
[image]

Does anyone have any idea on how to stop that tooltip from being blocked? I've tried increasing z-index to no avail.

Also, I don't want to use the DataTables built-in tooltip options because I need multiple different tooltips per cell.

EDIT: I've updated the fiddle to include DataTables and overflow:hidden

Comment: Did you include position: relative; (or absolute or fixed) with your z-index?

Comment: the position is set as `absolute` for .data-tooltip::before. You can see all the specific css in the fiddle

Comment: @Acoustic77 your demo doesn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/8nnwytbL/588/

Comment: looks like a css overflow problem....hard to help without a demo that reproduces problem. Your fiddle isn't very helpful. Use script to position the tooltip in absolute position based on cell position over top of table instead

Comment: @StefanBob the tooltip in the fiddle is cut off for you?

Comment: @charlietfl you are correct, when I removed `overflow:hidden;` from `table tbody td{}` in my css, the tooltip appears properly. The issue is that I need overflow hidden for some of my other columns. Is it possible to disable overflow hidden for just one column?

Comment: @Acoustic77 Sure, you can use `:not` in your selector http://jsfiddle.net/8nnwytbL/592/

Comment: @MichaelCoker that did it! Thanks for working with the limited info to figure that out. I didn't know about `:not`

Comment: @Acoustic77 awesome, no problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:not()` in your selector that applies `overflow: hidden;` to exclude a class from hiding the overflow. I added a class called `.tooltip` for cells that have a tooltip.

You can add the class manually, or using jQuery to add it to all cells that have a `.data-tooltip` child. Included examples of both in the demo.

```js
$('#datatable').DataTable({
  paging: false,
  info: false,
  dom: 'Bfrtip'
});

$('.data-tooltip').each(function() {
 $(this).closest('td').addClass('tooltip');
})
```

```css
.data-tooltip {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: help;
  padding: 4px;
}


/* Tooltip styling */

.data-tooltip::before {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  min-width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: opacity .6s;
}

.error1::before {
  content: "Hello";
}


/* Dynamic horizontal centering */

.tooltip-top::before {
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.tooltip-top::before {
  bottom: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}


/* Tooltip arrow styling/placement */

.tooltip-top::after {
  content: '';
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}


/* Dynamic horizontal centering for the tooltip */

.tooltip-top::after {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px;
}

.tooltip-top::after {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-width: 7px 6px 0;
  border-top-color: #555;
}


/* Show the tooltip when hovering */

.data-tooltip:hover:before,
.data-tooltip:hover:after {
  display: block;
  z-index: 50;
}

table tbody td {
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}

table tbody td:not(.tooltip) {
  overflow: hidden
}

body {
  margin: 60px 130px;
}


/* Demo purposes - ignore this margin */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered cw-table-list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row Number1</td>
      <td>1,2,<span class="data-tooltip tooltip-top error1">3</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row Number 2</td>
      <td class="tooltip">1,2,<span class="data-tooltip tooltip-top error1">3</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<span class="data-tooltip tooltip-top error1">Custom tooltip.</span>
```